# Python не работает

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.9

Я установил Python для Visual Studio Code. Решил проверить, работает ли он.

Написал:

```
print('Hello World!')
```

И нажал `Run Python File`. Но вместо того, чтобы выполнить код, в терминал выводится:

> Fatal python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
> Python runtime state: core initialized ModuleNotFoundError: no module named  'encodings'
> Current thread 0x00000764 (most recent call first)

Comment: *У меня Python 3.9.10

Comment: Как устанавливали сам Python? С официального сайта или из магазина приложений Windows?

Comment: Insolor, я скачивал Python с официального сайта.

Comment: Что у вас выведет, если через cmd выполнить команду `where python`?

Comment: Insolor, выводится путь к папке с python.exe

Comment: 1 - Нужен конкретный путь с конкретным именем экзешника. 2 - если запустить это экзешник запустит интерпретатор или выведет просто Python?

Comment: Установите заново на ваш персональный компьютер python через официальный сайт - https://www.python.org/ с параметром (Add Python 3.9.10 to PATH)
Если не поможет данное решение, проверьте расширениях в Visual Studio Code, поставлен ли у вас python,если нет вот ссылка на расширение - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

Comment: Insolor - когда я запускаю python.exe, окно консоли открывается и сразу же закрывается. Man4 - переустановка Python не помогает. Расширение Python у меня установлено.

Comment: Так, вроде я исправил эту ошибку, но теперь, когда я пытаюсь запустить программу выдаёт: Fatal python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding Python runtime state: core initialized ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'encodings' Current thread 0x00000764 (most recent call first) <no python frame>

Comment: > Fatal python error: - ну, Вы уже практически его забороли! Это почти победа. Вот похожий вопрос, в котором можно проверить свои действия: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings

Answer (score -1):

Вам достаточно просто скачать расширение python в самом vscode в разделе marketplace

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/817837)

Comment: @Павел Как это не содержится решение? Обьясните что по вашему решение?

Comment: Автор вопроса написал буквально: _Я установил Python для Visual Studio Code. Решил проверить, работает ли он._  И через год без месяца вы выдаёте "ценный" совет, хотя для данной проблемы на основном сайте навскидку обнаруживается несколько дубликатов: [один от 30 июня 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132755/importerror-no-module-named-encodings), [другой от 7 ноября 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725696/)